# How to concatenate variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to concatenate variables in inside a function and then return. In php we just put a period before the "=" but it is not working in javascript.

Can someone please help me figure this one out?

```
function NewMenuItem(){
    var output = "<input type='checkbox'> ";
    var output .= "<input type='text'> ";

    return output;
}
```

Comment: use the `+` operator: `"some string" + "some other string"`, [Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: `.` is the PHP concat operator. JS uses `+`.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20string%20concatenation

Comment: You can also do `output += "some more stuff"`

Comment: You'll benefit from giving the [MDN introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) a read-through. Especially if you already know another language, read through it so you know the syntax differences.

Comment: Read the fantastic manual.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator will concatenate two strings, ie. "Hello" + " World" //> "Hello World". Using `+=` is a short cut for assigning and concatenating a variable with its self.

ie. instead of:

```
var myVar = "somestring";
myVar = myVar + "another String";
```

you can just do:

```
var myVar = "somestring";
myVar += "another String";
```

For your problem:

```
function NewMenuItem() {
    //This is just a small example. The end result is more broader then this
    var output = "<input type='checkbox'> ";
    output += "<input type='text'> ";
    return output;
} //end of NewMenuItem(){
```

Comment: @torazaburo true, I guess thats just out of habit from the days of arithmetic. Updated.

Comment: agconti. Thank for the reply My mistake was that i was doing 
 var output = "<input type='checkbox'> ";
   var  output += "<input type='text'> ";

I put a var after the second variable. But your example worked. Thanks!

Comment: @eldan221 if I answered your question can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

"+=" is the standard way to concatenate in javascript;

```
var a = "yourname";
var b = "yourlastname";
var name = a + b;
var complete_name = "my name is: ";
complete_name += name;
```

result : my name is: yourname yourlastname

Comment: You can't use `+=` on a variable that is undefined. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: thanks i didnt see that basic error. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `Concat` function or with plus operator `(+)`.

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/chsfdsfj/) to see a working example.

Comment: `concat` function is deprecated/reccommnded against.