# Is there an easier method to concatenate variables using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing this:

```
var 1 = "http://www";
var 2 = ".google.";
var 3 = "com/";
```

then concatenating them together like this

`var link = 1+2+3;`

Is there an easier and more proficient way of doing this?

Comment: It sounds like you want an array.

Comment: I don't think you can get much more basic. And what do you mean by proficient?

Comment: IS declaring 1,2 as var valid ?

Comment: @yobro: link would have value as 6, and not "http://www.google.com/"

Comment: @yobro: Interesting! you are using the shortcut operator for concatenation, and asking for an easier way :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate variables in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815382/how-to-concatenate-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: I just thought there might of been an easier way to join variables together. i'm not the best at javascript hence the reason why i asked on stackoverflow. Obviously there isn't another more "quicker" way to do it, so that's the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what would be much easier than simple concatenation like you show, but you could put them in an Array and join it together.

(I fixed your variable names to make them valid.)

```
var first = "http://www";
var second = ".google.";
var third = "com/";

var link = [first, second, third].join("");
```

Or you could use the .concat() method.

```
var link = first.concat(second, third);
```

But both of these are longer than your original so I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: cheers for the answer mate, as you said, your method is slightly longer. So i think i'll just stick with the method im using. Just thought there was an easier way to do it. cause adding each one together like that looks so amateur :P

Comment: There are some browsers where *join* is faster, but in most (especially modern) browsers `+` is hugely faster.