# How can i concatenate variable between two strings in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate `var` value between two strings to get my code work, but I'm getting error of unexpected token or invalid string while trying different ways: to concatenate using `concat` function or with dot between string.

Below the code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var href = 'a[href="'.concat(hash) '"]';
alert(href);
if(hash != "") {
 jQuery(".tab-content-panel").hide();
 var id = jQuery(hash).show();
 jQuery('.tabs-custom-nav li a').removeClass('current');
//jQuery('.tabs-custom-nav li a[href="'.hash "]').addClass('current');

//alert(id);
  }
 //alert(hash);
```

Comment: Solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815382/how-to-concatenate-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use concat: in fact, you can't use it, since it is an [Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). You can either use `+` to concatenate strings:

```
var href = 'a[href="' + hash + '"]';
```

Or use [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var href = `a[href="${hash}"]`;
```

Comment: thanks your answer is very impressive increased my knowledge regard javascript will accept answer after 7 minutes

Comment: because few people know here the curiosity of getting solutions of problem. @Rajesh

Comment: @KamranHassan We are here to help. Sharing and closing gives you access to multiple solutions and long discussions from which you will learn a lot. With just answering, we are creating redundant content which will go unmonitored

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple + to concat strings? But please be aware of security risks you may run into. If this does what you expect, fine. But keep security issues in mind.

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
var href = 'a[href="'+hash+'"]';
alert(href);
```